# Power of the car brake system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, work, power

When I have a car that descends from a stationary position along an inclined plane. If I have that the driver uses the brake system to keep the speed constant, going through 50 m in 10s.

Then if I have to determine the power of the brake system if I assume there is no friction between the wheels and the asphalt, I have considered that since the brake system has to do negative work, since it opposes the movement, then the **power** is necessarily *negative*, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if the car is slowing down and is not moving *up* a slope then its brakes are, in effect, doing negative work on the car since the car is losing kinetic energy. You can also think of this as the car doing positive work on the brakes. With standard brakes the kinetic energy goes into heating the brakes. With regenerative braking some of the energy is stored and is available for reuse.

However, if there is no friction between the tyres and the road then the brakes cannot slow the car down - all they do is stop the wheels from turning. In that situation what you need is an anchor or a [drogue parachute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drogue_parachute) !